# Python writing on a text file

Tags: python, file

So I have an xml file, a python code, and a fileList.txt.

I have to extract the path from the xml file (it's done), and write it to a fileList.txt file. I have no problem writing it, but I would like to check in that file if the path isn't already present. I just can get through this. Here's what I wrote. I tried with a for, but it didn't work. Thanks in advance

```
fileList.txt: 
USM/src/
```

python:

```
for racine in rootElements.findall('racine'):
    path = racine.find('path').text 
    if path != None: 
        f_path = f_path + path + "/"  
print f_path

file = open('fileList.txt','r') 

while 1:
     ligne = file.readline()
     if(ligne == f_path):
         print("path already present")
         sys.exit(0)
     else:
         break
file.close()

file = open('fileList.txt','a') 
f_path = f_path + "\n"  
file.write(f_path)      

file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your infinite `while` loop will only ever execute once; you check if the first line is a match, then if it is you exit the program entirely and if it's not you exit the loop.

Something like this will work better:

```
with open('fileList.txt','r+') as myfile: #file is a builtin, don't name your file 'file'
    for line in myfile:
         if line.strip() == f_path:
              print "path already present"
              break
    else:
        myfile.write(f_path)
```

Comment: I got type object is not iterable. What is exacty your "line"

Comment: `line` is just a variable that gets assigned to each line in the file by the for loop. Are you doing `for line in file` without opening something called `file`? That would give that message, because `file` is a built-in type (hence my example using "`myfile`").

Answer (score 1):

The others are good, but have the mistake of using a file object for an iterable. To fix that, use the `File.readlines()` method to create a list of iterables. Here is the entire code:

```
for racine in rootElements.findall('racine'):
    path = racine.find('path').text 
    if path != None: 
        f_path = f_path + path + "/"  
print f_path

file = open('fileList.txt','r') 

with open('fileList.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines() : # here is the fix
        if line.strip() == f_path:
            print("path already present")
            sys.exit(0)

with open('fileList.txt','a') as myfile:
    f_path = f_path + "\n"  
    myfile.write(f_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

`file.readline()` will include the line-terminator character, '`\n`'. You could try `file.readline().strip()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Also, your `while` loop doesn't look right. It never loops more than once, because either it finds a match on the first line and invokes `sys.exit(0)`, or it does not and hits the `break` to end the loop.

A better approach instead of the `while` loop might be:

```
for line in file:
    if line.strip() == f_path:
        print("path already present")
        sys.exit(0)
file.close()
```

---

*EDIT* - You report getting "type object is not iterable". That generally means that the sequence in the for loop (here "`file`") is not of an iterable type. In your example code, `file` was the name of a file you had previously opened. This is a bad name for a variable, because Python already uses `file` as the class for file objects. Perhaps you have changed the code to use a different name for the file variable, and not updated my example to match? Here's a complete version of your program that should work:

```
for racine in rootElements.findall('racine'):
    path = racine.find('path').text 
    if path != None: 
        f_path = f_path + path + "/"  
print f_path

file = open('fileList.txt','r') 

with open('fileList.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for ligne in myfile:
        if ligne.strip() == f_path:
            print("path already present")
            sys.exit(0)

with open('fileList.txt','a') as myfile:
    f_path = f_path + "\n"  
    myfile.write(f_path)
```

Comment: I get this 'type' object is not iterable. Is it line or ligne as I called it ? Where do you put your readline ?                                    `for ligne in file:
  ligne = fichier.readline().strip()`

Comment: You should call `readline` on the file object:  `for ligne in fichier: ligne = fichier.readline().strip() ` (Better not use `file`, in some versions of Python it is an alias for `open` and that could be confusing).  However, that might be inefficient.

Comment: @Yanis I've updated the post. I think both Wooble (no relation!) and my answer assumed that the rest of your program remained unchanged from your question. I've posted your entire program fragment with changes made to the appropriate places. However, even that isn't your whole program, as you must load rootElements somewhere. If it doesn't work you'll need to explain in more detail what your program does and what is going wrong.